# Runtime error 1004 - Unable to get the PageRange property of the PivotTable class

Tags: excel, vba, range, pivot-table

When the code is applied to a pivot table that has no `PageRange` property the code fails with the error in the title

I tried to apply a boolean variable to

```
sh.PivotTables(i).PageRange
```

but that did not work either

```
 Sub TestPivotPaste2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set sh = wb.Worksheets(7)
    c = sh.PivotTables.Count

    If c > 0 Then

        For i = 1 To c
            If Not sh.PivotTables(i).PageRange.Count = 0 Then
                Debug.Print c
            Else
                GoTo nextpiv
            End If
            nextpiv:
        Next i
    Else
    MsgBox ("NoPivot")
    End If

   End Sub
```

the expected result is to be able to discern the pivot tables where the PageRange property is true or false, but it only works when the range exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
Function pageRangeExists(pt as PivotTable) as Boolean

    Dim test as Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set test = pt.PageRange
    On Error Go To 0

    pageRangeExists = Not test Is Nothing

End Function
```

Since `PageRange` is a range object, you have to test if the range exists or is valid first, as trying to act against a range that is not there will produce an error.

And with that your `for loop` can be simplified

```
   For i = 1 To c
       If pageRangeExists(sh.PivotTables(i)) Then
           Debug.Print c
       End If
   Next i
```

The `GoTo` statement is superfluous as it is logic already embedded in a `for loop`.

Comment: Thank you, test existence of the range object is what I was trying to do unsuccessfully. I am not sure how to use that function within my code, though I understand why you are proposing it.

Comment: I see now the rest of your comment and I used it as you suggested it and it works great.
Thank you very much

Comment: @EliseoDiFolco - I modified my answer. Should be `If pageRangeExists`, I believe, since you want to `debug.print c` if the page range is there.